# Preprocessing iterator

Tags: c++, c++14, iterator

After tweaking semantics a lot, it ended up being a very poor object version of `std::transform<>()` that can be used with other std algorithms.

Basically the iterator wraps a provided iterator, creating an output iterator and applies supplied functor when dereferenced and assigned to. The caveat is that users will need to identify parameter type themselves, which can be error prone, but might open opportunities for other usages. Input type should not be cv qualified, because it has overloads for both const lvalue reference and rvalue reference. If the user wishes to take parameter by value, they would need to write another functor for that.

```
#ifndef SUNRISE_PREPROCESSING_ITERATOR_HPP
#define SUNRISE_PREPROCESSING_ITERATOR_HPP

#include <iterator>

namespace shino
{
    template<typename Functor, typename InputType, typename Iterator>
    class preprocessing_iterator :
            public std::iterator<std::output_iterator_tag,
                    InputType, void, void, void>
    {
        Functor functor;

        Iterator iterator;
    public:
        preprocessing_iterator(const Functor &f, const Iterator &it) :
                functor(f),
                iterator(it)
        {}

        preprocessing_iterator(Functor &&f, Iterator &&it) :
                functor(f),
                iterator(it)
        {}

        class proxy
        {
            friend class preprocessing_iterator;

            Iterator &iterator;
            Functor &f;
        public:
            using value_type = InputType;

            proxy &operator=(const value_type &value)
            {
                *iterator = f(value);
                return *this;
            }

            proxy &operator=(value_type &&value)
            {
                *iterator = f(value);
                return *this;
            }

        private:
            proxy(Iterator &it, Functor &functor) :
                    iterator(it),
                    f(functor)
            {}
        };

        proxy operator*()
        {
            return proxy(iterator, functor);
        }

        preprocessing_iterator &operator++()
        {
            ++iterator;
            return *this;
        }

        preprocessing_iterator operator++(int)
        {
            auto copy = *this;
            ++iterator; //might exhibit different behavior sometimes
            return copy;
        }

        const Iterator& internal_iterator() const
        {
            return iterator;
        }

        const Functor& internal_functor() const
        {
            return functor;
        }

        void swap(preprocessing_iterator& other)
        {
            using std::swap;
            swap(other.functor, functor);
            swap(other.iterator, iterator);
        }
    };

    template<typename Functor, typename InputType, typename Iterator>
    bool operator==(const preprocessing_iterator<Functor, InputType, Iterator>& lhs,
                   const preprocessing_iterator<Functor, InputType, Iterator>& rhs)
    {
        return lhs.internal_iterator() == rhs.internal_iterator();
    };

    template <typename Functor, typename InputType, typename Iterator>
    bool operator!=(const preprocessing_iterator<Functor, InputType, Iterator>& lhs,
                    const preprocessing_iterator<Functor, InputType, Iterator>& rhs)
    {
        return !(lhs == rhs);
    };
}

namespace std
{
    template <typename Functor, typename InputType, typename Iterator>
    void swap(shino::preprocessing_iterator<Functor, InputType, Iterator>& lhs,
              shino::preprocessing_iterator<Functor, InputType, Iterator>& rhs)
    {
        lhs.swap(rhs);
    };
}



#endif //SUNRISE_PREPROCESSING_ITERATOR_HPP
```

Usage:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

void convert_strings_to_ints()
{
    std::vector<std::string> v{"23", "25", "27"}; //just random numbers
    std::vector<int> output(v.size());

    auto string_to_int = [](const std::string& x)
    {
        return std::stoi(x);
    };

    shino::preprocessing_iterator<decltype(string_to_int),
            std::string, std::vector<int>::iterator> conversion_iterator(string_to_int, output.begin());

    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), conversion_iterator);

    std::cout << "Output after converting v to vector of ints\n";

    for (const auto& element: output)
    {
        std::cout << element << '\n';
    }
}

int main()
{
    convert_strings_to_ints();
}
```

As it can be seen, the best usage case is writing adapters. I've tried to lower the overhead as much as possible, but if `Functor` is not lightweight to copy, it might become a problem if iterators are copied too much.

My specific concerns are:

- Easy of use. This is the main issue.
- Obscure places that should be documented. From the first sight of my familiar nothing seems strange or ambiguous.
- Any place where I could accidentally cause very big slow down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your goal is to make this example code:

```
shino::preprocessing_iterator<decltype(string_to_int), std::string, std::vector<int>::iterator>
    conversion_iterator(string_to_int, output.begin());

std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), conversion_iterator);
```

have an effect equivalent to this present-day code:

```
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), output.begin(), string_to_int);
```

(When I say it that way, it seems almost a little silly, doesn't it? ;))

---

The first usability improvement I'd make is to notice that your iterator type is fundamentally related to `std::transform` (actually you already noticed this) and change its name to `shino::transform_iterator`.

It also looks analogous to `std::back_insert_iterator`, in the sense that it holds references to some other objects and its constructor is really awkward to type out by hand. So I'd follow the practice of the STL here by creating a helper function. The logical name would be `shino::make_transform_iterator`, but you could instead follow traditional practice (cf. `back_inserter`) and call it simply `std::transformer`. It looks like this:

```
template<class InputType, class OutputIterator, class F>
auto transformer(F f, OutputIterator dest)
    -> transform_iterator<F, InputType, OutputIterator>
{
    return {std::move(f), std::move(dest)};
}
```

So now your target example code looks like this:

```
auto conversion_iterator = shino::transformer<std::string>(string_to_int, output.begin());
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), conversion_iterator);
```

That's an improvement!

---

Next, I notice that `class InputType` feels out-of-place. We don't actually *use* it for anything. So I'd try to get rid of it, by hunting down each place that your code depends on `InputType` and rewriting it to *not* use `InputType`.

For example, instead of

```
proxy &operator=(const value_type &value)
{
    *iterator = f(value);
    return *this;
}

proxy &operator=(value_type &&value)
{
    *iterator = f(value);
    return *this;
}
```

I would try to write simply

```
template<class U>
proxy& operator=(U&& value)
{
    *iterator = f(std::forward<U>(value));
    return *this;
}
```

I was a little worried that this might do the wrong thing when chaining `transform_iterator`s together, but my first trivial test case worked, so I'm going to ignore that nagging worry. :)  That test case was:

```
auto p1 = shino::transformer<std::string>(string_to_int, output.begin());
auto p2 = shino::transformer<std::string>([](std::string x){ return x+"1"; }, p1);
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), p2);
```

---

The other place where you use `InputType` is in your inheritance from `std::iterator<std::output_iterator_tag, InputType, void, void, void>`. Fortunately, [inheritance from `std::iterator` is no longer considered *à la mode*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471019/can-should-i-inherit-from-stl-iterator/22211034#22211034); in fact, `std::iterator` itself may become deprecated soon! So what you should do is simply

```
template<typename Functor, typename Iterator>
class transform_iterator
{
    Functor functor;
    Iterator iterator;

  public:
    using iterator_category = std::output_iterator_tag;
    using difference_type = void;
    using value_type = void;
    using pointer = void;
    using reference = void;
```

Notice that [`std::iterator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) strongly encourages you to put the `using value_type = void;` line; and `pointer`, `reference`, and `difference_type` also become `void` by analogy to [`std::back_insert_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator).

*Notice that these member typedefs must be `public`.* (libc++ is happy if they're private; but libstdc++ isn't.)

---

Lastly, your specialization of `std::swap` is also no longer *à la mode*. Instead of interjecting your own code into the `std` namespace, you should simply provide a `shino::swap(transform_iterator&, transform_iterator&)` that can be found by [ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).

Your `swap` code itself is 100% correct and reasonable; you should just change that `namespace std` to `namespace shino`, and you'll be in business.

The expected way for users (such as STL algorithms) to swap two `transform_iterators` `a` and `b` is:

```
using std::swap;  // in case no ADL swap exists
swap(a, b);  // look for an ADL swap; fall back on std::swap if needed
```

---

I have no particular comment on the efficiency or subtle correctness of how your code (or my revised code) handles the forwarding of functors and such. I'd probably just try to write some tests for that (e.g. what if the functor in question is move-only?), and fix any issues they find, and then move on with my life. ;)

---

[Here's a Wandbox of the code after these changes.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/vAZTBlO7wpEJd1XP)

Comment: Great review! And even better naming!

Comment: One small nitpick: most functions that take iterators and functors have the iterators first, and the functions/predicate last, e.g. `transform`, `copy_if`. Other than that, the review is spot on.