# C++17 extract/insert iterators

Tags: c++, iterator, c++17

[(Here is a link to this same code on Wandbox)](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/pT51Ak4gg8WHXyun)

C++17 introduces member functions `extract` and `insert` on node-based containers (such as `set` and `map`) so that single elements can be transferred from container A to container B without any move operations. It also adds member function `merge` to transfer *all* contents of container A into container B. But there's no "range `merge`" function provided by the STL as far as I can tell. So, inspired by [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/155866/preprocessing-iterator), I decided to write an iterator adaptor similar to [`std::move_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/move_iterator) but which can be used to *extract and insert* instead of *moving*. Here's my usage example:

```
// snipped the definitions of classes K and V, but see the Wandbox if you care

int main()
{
    using KV = std::pair<K,V>;
    std::map<K,V> m1({
        KV{ "k1", "v1" },
        KV{ "k2", "v2" },
        KV{ "k3", "v3" },
    });
    std::map<K,V> m2;

    puts("Moving elements from m1 to m2...");
#if 0
    // the old boring way
    for (auto it = m1.begin(); it != m1.end(); ) {
        m2.insert( m1.extract(it++) );
    }
#else
    // the shiny new way
    auto begin = my::extract_iterator(m1, m1.begin());
    auto end = my::extract_iterator(m1, m1.end());
    auto out = my::insert_iterator(m2);
    std::copy(begin, end, out);
#endif
    puts("...done!");

    std::cout << "Contents of m1:" << std::endl;
    for (auto&& [k, v]: m1) {
        std::cout << k << ' ' << v << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Contents of m2:" << std::endl;
    for (auto&& [k, v]: m2) {
        std::cout << k << ' ' << v << std::endl;
    }
}
```

And here's the implementation:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

namespace my
{
    template<typename Container>
    class insert_iterator
    {
        Container *container;

    public:
        using iterator_category = std::output_iterator_tag;
        using difference_type = void;
        using value_type = void;
        using pointer = void;
        using reference = void;

        insert_iterator(Container& c) : container(&c) {}

        insert_iterator& operator*() { return *this; }
        insert_iterator& operator++() { return *this; }
        insert_iterator operator++(int) { return *this; }

        template<class N>
        insert_iterator& operator=(N&& nh)
        {
            container->insert(std::forward<N>(nh));
            return *this;
        }
    };

    template<typename Container, typename Iterator>
    class extract_iterator
    {
        Container *container;
        Iterator iterator;
        bool secretly_advanced = false;

    public:
        using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;
        using difference_type = void;
        using value_type = void;
        using pointer = void;
        using reference = void;

        extract_iterator(Container& c, Iterator it) : container(&c), iterator(std::move(it)) {}

        auto operator*() {
            assert(!secretly_advanced);
            secretly_advanced = true;
            return container->extract(iterator++);
        }
        extract_iterator& operator++() {
            if (!secretly_advanced) ++iterator; 
            secretly_advanced = false;
            return *this;
        }
        extract_iterator operator++(int) {
            auto copy = *this;
            if (!secretly_advanced) ++iterator; 
            secretly_advanced = false;
            return copy;
        }
        bool operator==(const extract_iterator& o) const {
            return secretly_advanced == o.secretly_advanced && iterator == o.iterator;
        }
        bool operator!=(const extract_iterator& o) const { return !(*this == o); }
    };
} // namespace my
```

Notice that I'm using the default rules for class template parameter type deduction.

Notice that my input iterator (`extract_iterator`) sets its `value_type` to `void`. I'm not 100% sure that's kosher.

The `secretly_advanced` stuff is unfortunately necessary because libstdc++ implements its `std::copy` as something like

```
while (first != last) {
    *d_first++ = *first;
    ++first;
}
```

instead of

```
while (first != last) {
    *d_first++ = *first++;
}
```

and evaluating `*first` in my case invalidates `first.iterator`, so I figured the best thing to do was to advance it inside `operator*` itself and just keep track of whether it'd already been secretly advanced or not.

If I missed out on a chance to use some exciting new C++17ism, please tell me!

Comment: Can you provide a `K` and `V` so that we can compile this?  Your link doesn't include any code (unless it's hidden in a script somewhere, but it would still be better in the question, for permanence).

Comment: @TobySpeight, definitions of `K` and `V` are right before main. I think that definitions are not that necessary, since it is more or less obvious what they are doing.

Comment: What do you mean, "right before main"? - all I see is "*Here's my usage example:

// snipped the definitions of classes K and V, but see the Wandbox if you care

int main()*".  No definition.

Comment: Can I just `using K = std::string`? and the same for `V`?

Comment: @TobySpeight, the code is in the link. No, replacing it with `std::string` will strip off some small stuff. Though the main point should still remain.

Comment: Then can you provide a working link - or, better, include the code in the body of the question where we can see it?  Thanks.

Comment: @TobySpeight, I'm not the author of the question :) For me link works fine. Writing `using K = std::string` and for V should work fine as well.

Comment: The test case on Wandbox uses a particular `K` and `V` with instrumented constructors and assignment operators, in order to "prove" that no move-constructions or assignments take place during the `std::copy`. But yeah, @TobySpeight, my intention is definitely that you ought to be able to use these iterators with any `K` and `V` of your choosing.

Comment: @TobySpeight: If I'm reading between your lines correctly and you really aren't using a Javascript-capable browser, (A) that is amazing, and (B) here's a Javascript-free version just for you: http://melpon.org/wandbox/nojs/gcc-head/permlink/s1lpmNxyKFSYPXFK

Answer (score 1):

It seems that GCC's implementation of C++17 isn't complete enough to compile your code (at least at 6.3.0), but I can offer a few comments:

### Headers

Your includes don't match your uses.  I found I needed

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>
```

(some of the others are needed by your `main()`, but shouldn't belong in your header file).

### Pointer to container object

You accept a container as a reference, but then store its address.  It might be clearer to use a reference, as it cannot be null:

```
    Container &container;
```

However, if you do this, then an iterator into a given container can't be assigned from an iterator to a different container.  In other words, `operator=()` would be constrained to work only when both iterators reference the same container, which might be too restrictive, and certainly surprising compared with the Standard Library iterators.

### C asserts

I'm not convinced that this assert is good:

```
        assert(!secretly_advanced);
```

Asserts are good for testing invariants, but this looks like it's checking that client code has used it in the prescribed manner.  If you're to check this at all, it might be better to raise an exception.  On the other hand, since you aren't checking that the user doesn't dereference the `end()` iterator, perhaps it's more appropriate to behave like the standard library, and not impose checking.

Comment: I think if I store a reference, my iterator is no longer assignable. I also think I get `iterator_traits` for free, given that I'm providing all the appropriate member typedefs (AFAIK). ...Or, in what way were you thinking it'd help to specialize `iterator_traits`? (Your other points are well taken.)

Comment: I think you're right on both counts - I've amended my answer.

Comment: Also, I found the use of `insert_operator` as its own proxy object to be a bit strange - but I couldn't pin down exactly what made me uncomfortable about it.  I guess it's just not a pattern I'd seen before.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to discussion at [the San Francisco C++ meetup](https://www.meetup.com/ACCU-Bay-Area/events/237092395/), here is a definite flaw in my original code:

```
    template<class N>
    insert_iterator& operator=(N&& nh)
    {
        container->insert(std::forward<N>(nh));
        return *this;
    }
```

A guideline was proposed: "Unconstrained forwarding references are always a bad idea." I don't yet 100% agree with that guideline, but I definitely agree when forwarding references are used in ways that might be mistaken for special member functions. The above code breaks usages like the following:

```
auto out1 = my::insert_iterator(m2);
auto out2 = my::insert_iterator(m2);
out1 = out2;
```

The above fails because `out1 = out2` tries to find a match for `insert_iterator::operator=(insert_iterator&)`. This would be an okay match for the implicitly defaulted copy-assignment operator `insert_iterator::operator=(const insert_iterator&)`, but unfortunately it's a *perfect* match for the specialization `insert_operator::operator=(N&&) [with N=insert_iterator&]`. So we end up trying to call the equivalent of

```
container->insert(out2);
```

and we get a compiler error.

In some cases the appropriate fix would be to constrain the template with `std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<N>, insert_iterator>>`; but in this case the appropriate fix is just to Be Less Clever.

```
    insert_iterator& operator=(typename Container::node_type&& nh)
    {
        container->insert(std::move(nh));
        return *this;
    }
```

---

I'm also now vaguely worried about exception-safety.

The good news is that node handles are fundamentally memory-leak-proof; if you destroy a node handle without inserting it anywhere, then the destructor frees the node (and its contents) for you.

The worrisome news is that `Container::insert` can definitely throw (most obviously, if `T::operator<` resp. `std::hash<T>::operator()` throws), and it wouldn't surprise me if `Container::extract` could throw too. Do we need to do anything special to deal with exceptions here? I think the answer is "no, we get the basic exception guarantee that nothing will go horribly wrong as long as you don't try to use those iterators again," but I haven't formally explored it.